# CefSharp - Get result of AJAX request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, cefsharp

I am really new to CefSharps Chromium browser and have difficulty figuring out how to get the result of a jquery ajax request.

My first attempt was to pass my AJAX requesto to `EvaluateScriptAsync`. In fact the script works. It does exactly what I want, but I do not get any results/status codes, because my Cef-Task does not wait until AJAX has completed its work.

Here an example (just a sample code):

```
var tasks = pdBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
    (function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: ""POST"",
            dataType: ""json"",
            cache: false,
            url: ""_resources/php/ajaxRequests.php"",
            async: false,
            data: {
                action: ""insertCrossPlatform"",
                type: """",
                values: JSON.stringify(""foo bar"")
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (typeof response === 'string' && response.substring(0, 5) == ""ERROR"")
                {
                    return response;
                }
                    else
                {
                    //pageReload();
                    return ""OK"";
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                return errorThrown + ""\n"" + xhr.responseText;
            },
            complete: function() {
                return ""COMPLETE"";
            }
        });
    })();", null);

tasks.ContinueWith(t =>
{
     if (!t.IsFaulted)
    {
        var response = t.Result;
        if (response.Success)
        {
            if (response.Result != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(response.Result.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(response.Message, "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
}, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Afterwards I have read that there is a SchemeHandler, but I do not properly understand how to implement it. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you returned a value in your anonymous closure then that would be returned as the result of `EvaluateScriptAsync`. You could return the params as json, then execute a `WebRequest` in `C#`, when complete execute more `JS` to update your `UI`. I don't particularly recommend this approach, see alternatives below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `SchemeHandler` is unlikely to be suitable in this scenario, you would typically implement a `SchemeHandler` when your providing the response.

Most people choose to bind an object, and call a method on their bound object when they wish to communicate with the parent application. See the `FAQ` for an example. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

With `49.0.0` you can implement `ResponseFilter` to gain access to the underlying response buffer, it's complex and not well documented, so if your not comfortable digging through reference `C++` code then this option isn't for you. Here's a reference https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.Example/Filters/PassThruResponseFilter.cs#L17

Comment: the link to the wiki is really helpful. i didn't think of binding an object... this could really be a good solution for me. I'm going to test it asap this evening.

In fact, no, I'm not really comfortable with C++. I know some basic C++ but I think it is not as deep enough to understand how to use that method. I will give it a try as soon as I have a free minute, but in the meantime I am pretty sure going for the first solution, binding that object.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I did was create an element on the page through javascript with an ID that is the response of the ajax call. So for example, when you make an ajax call assign an ID to the ajax call.

When the ajax call returns, write an element on the page with the pre-assigned id and callback information. Then you can just use cefsharp to read the element content from the page and this will be your callback information.

```
var myDivElement =document.getElementById('textareaInfo');

if( myDivElement === null)
{
var input = document.createElement('textarea'); 
input.id = "textareaInfo";
input.value = "Test"
input.rows="4";
input.cols="50";
input.style="height:100%;width:900px;"

var dom = document.getElementsByClassName("page-body")[0];
dom.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', input)
}
```

> Then later with ajax

```
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

var _holder = callbackObj;

callbackObj.showMessage(""ajax"");

$.ajax({

  url: root + '/posts/1',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  method: 'GET',
complete: function(data){

},
 success: function(response) {

     $(#'textareaInfo').value(response);                
                        }
}).then(function(data) {
   callbackObj.showMessage(data);
});
```

> Then read the texarea from cefsharp in c#

chromeBrowser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(function()...$(textareaInfo).value).Result

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostMessage javascript method to notify .NET application:

```
CefSharp.PostMessage('Your data Here');
```

Here is .NET code example for headless browser:

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("", null, RequestContext);
browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if ((string)e.Message.notificationid == "notification1")
                {
                    // Your processing code goes here
                }
            };

browser.Load(destinationUrl);
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("(function() { ... ; CefSharp.PostMessage({data: data, notificationid: 'notification1'});})()");
```